# Woocommerce: How to get variations stock-status

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have this function to personalize my product page a little. Inside my child-themes function.php I added this:

```
function change_product_summary_germanized(){
    global $product;

    if ($product->is_type('variable')) {

        $shopmarks = wc_gzd_get_single_product_shopmarks();

        foreach ($shopmarks as $shopmark) {
            $type = $shopmark->get_type();
            switch ($type) {
                case 'unit_price':
                    $shopmark->remove();
                    add_action('woocommerce_before_single_variation', 'woocommerce_gzd_template_single_price_unit', 20);
                    add_action('woocommerce_before_single_variation', 'custom_unit_price_title', 19);
                    break;
                case 'legal':
                    $shopmark->remove();
                    add_action('woocommerce_before_single_variation', 'woocommerce_gzd_template_single_legal_info', 40);
                    break;
                case 'delivery_time':
                    $shopmark->remove();
                    // if ( $product->is_in_stock() ) {
                        add_action('woocommerce_before_single_variation', 'woocommerce_gzd_template_single_delivery_time_info', 50);
                    // }
                    break;

            }
        }
    }
}
add_filter('woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'change_product_summary_germanized');
```

Works fine but as you can see I commented out an if-clause that I am having trouble with. I tried all different kinds of ways to not add the delivery-time, when the selected variation is out of stock.

Examples of what I have tried so far :

```
if( $product->is_in_stock() ) {...}
if( $product->get_stock_quantity() > 0 ) {...}
if( sizeof($product->get_available_variations()) > 0) {...}

...
```

I am pretty new to this. Anybody can point out to me, what's the way to go here?

Comment: Check [this hook](https://gist.github.com/plugin-republic/7429a72127e527ad1c68821773001863)

Comment: This would disallow to select the variation, right? That's not quite what I am looking for. Another approach would be to hide the delivery-time-element with JQuery. General lack of Wordpress-understatement: How would you access the `$variation`-variable, without using the `woocommerce_variation_is_active`-Hook? So I could just hook to `wp_head`. Can I just write `global $variation;`, like I do with `$product`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many may agree that this is terrible work, but I achieved what I wanted on a complicated way. A few months ago I built a function to get product-prices on my own way. It's leaned on something I found online, but I can't find the reference anymore. Anyway, I added some JQuery to hide/show elements depending on if other elements are visible.

```
function custom_wc_template_single_price(){
global $product;
if ($product->is_type('variable')):
    $prices = array(
        $product->get_variation_price('min', true),
        $product->get_variation_price('max', true)
    );
    $price = $prices[0] !== $prices[1] ? sprintf(__('ab %1$s', 'woocommerce'), wc_price($prices[0])) : wc_price($prices[0]);
    $prices = array(
        $product->get_variation_regular_price('min', true),
        $product->get_variation_regular_price('max', true)
    );
    sort($prices);
    $saleprice = $prices[0] !== $prices[1] ? sprintf(__('ab %1$s', 'woocommerce'), wc_price($prices[0])) : wc_price($prices[0]);

    if ($price !== $saleprice && $product->is_on_sale()) {
        $price = '<del>' . $saleprice . $product->get_price_suffix() . '</del> <ins>' . $price . $product->get_price_suffix() . '</ins>';
    }

    ?>
    <style>
        div.woocommerce-variation-price,
        div.woocommerce-variation-availability,
        div.hidden-variable-price {
            height: 0px !important;
            overflow: hidden;
            position: relative;
            line-height: 0px !important;
            font-size: 0% !important;
            visibility: hidden !important;
        }

        p.price {
            margin-bottom: 12px;
        }

        p.availability {
            margin-bottom: 4px;
        }
    </style>
    <script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
            setTimeout(function () {
                if (0 < $('input.variation_id').val() && null != $('input.variation_id').val()) {
                    if ($('p.availability'))
                        $('p.availability').remove();

                    $('p.price:not(.price-unit)').html($('div.woocommerce-variation-price > span.price').html());
                    if ($('div.legal-price-info > p.stock').length === 0) {
                        $('div.legal-price-info').append('<p class="availability">' + $('div.woocommerce-variation-availability').html() + '</p>');
                    }
                }
            }, 300);
            $('input').blur(function () {
                if (0 < $('input.variation_id').val() && null != $('input.variation_id').val()) {

                    if ($('.price p.availability') || $('.price p.stock'))
                        $('p.price:not(.price-unit) p').each(function () {
                            $(this).remove();
                        });

                    if ($('div.legal-price-info > p.availability'))
                        $('div.legal-price-info > p:not(.wc-gzd-additional-info)').remove();

                    $('p.price:not(.price-unit)').html($('div.woocommerce-variation-price > span.price').html());

                    $('div.legal-price-info').append('<p class="availability">' + $('div.woocommerce-variation-availability').html() + '</p>');

                    if ($('div.legal-price-info > p.stock').length !== 0) {
                        $('p.delivery-time-info').hide();
                        $('div.woocommerce-variation-add-to-cart').hide();
                    } else {
                        $('p.delivery-time-info').show();
                        $('div.woocommerce-variation-add-to-cart').show();
                    }
                } else {
                    $('p.price:not(.price-unit)').html($('div.hidden-variable-price').html());
                    if ($('p.availability'))
                        $('p.availability').remove();
                }
            })
        });

    </script>
    <?php
    echo '<p class="price">' . $price . '</p>
    <div class="hidden-variable-price" >' . $price . '</div>';
endif;
```